# Rails Devise login - can select any role (one to many relation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to implement Devise login not only with email and password but also with Role. User can have more than one role and he can choose anyone role while he login.

```
Model:
  User  -  has_many :roles (Devise applied)
  Role  -  belongs_to :user
```

I want to authenticate user along with role and remember the role selected while login.

**Note:**
Rails 5.2.1
Devise 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `rails generate migration add_firstname_and_lastname_to_users email:string` produces a migration like this

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
  end
end
```

In that case you have to manually an extra line to change

```
class AddEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

And then `run rake db:migrate`

in the app controller

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :last_name
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:first_name, :last_name]
  end
```